# Parsing Apache Error.Log in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, awk, ssh, error-log

I tried to parse Apache error log using the following command:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log |  awk  '$8 ~ /(400|500)/ {print $6}'
```

Where i am trying to only view 400 error OR 500 error. But when i run that ssh command, it doesn't return anything. In other words, nothing is displayed on the screen.

For the record, i have try to purportedly point my browser to a bogus URL page so that it generates 400 error / 500 error.

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: Please paste snippet of error.log

Comment: @Varun i am sorry it is not possible since this is run on a production server. The content of error.log will contains both "notice" and "warning" level, and it builds up so fast, i wont be able to capture the even the last 100 lines.

Comment: The command syntax looks OK to me but it is possible that field $8 does not have have error code 400 or 500. Just a wild guess replace $8 with $0 and try awk  '$0 ~ /(400|500)/ {print $6}'. It is difficult to figure out problem unless input data is there.

Comment: wrt `i am sorry it is not possible since this is run on a production server.` - no one expects you to post real data but we do expect you to create artificial data that follows the same format as your real data. It's not that much effort to modify half a dozen lines of your real data to create something you can show us to help us to help you. Also you said `when i run that ssh command` but you don't show an ssh command - edit your question to show the command line you are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Either the log file you are reading is wrong or your awk script is. Try this

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log |  grep GET
```

This will tell you if you are actually seeing `GET` requests. Then try

```
cat /usr/local/var/log/apache2/access_log | awk '{print $7}'
```

on a normal apache box this will print the request URL. If this is printing anything you know you have a working log. Then use this

```
cat ..../access_log | awk '{print $9}'| egrep "(400|500)"
```

to see the requests with the errors. Note. I normally only use awk for splitting on separators because as things get any more complicated I use more pipes then then Perl.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, i tried the tail (first suggestion) but still having similar result. I double checked that i am pointing to the right file.

Comment: Are you seeing anything when you just tail the file? If not then you are either not logging or looking at the wrong file.